# Want my acount to be deleted, not interested

Tags: support, status-completed

I joined today, took a tour of this site and found it a weird Q&A spot.  I couldn't find the option to delete my account.  I request the ISE team or moderators to delete it.  Thanks.  Goodbye.

Answer (score 3):

You can deleted your account yourself. How is described in our [help-center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) see for example [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).